# is the `names_sep` argument in `tidyr::pivot_longer` flexible on string splitting?

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I have some random effect coefficients extracted from a R model object. For a random intercept, they look like this:

```
xx <- data.frame(
    `Estimate.Intercept` = c(-0.1, -0.2), 
    `Est.Error.Intercept` = c(0.7, 0.8), 
    `Q5.Intercept` = c(-1.5, -1.4), 
    `Q95.Intercept` = c(0.7, 0.8)
)
```

I'm formatting the data for a `.csv` report and trying to generate a 'long' data.frame/tibble with `term_type` taken from the first part of the column name and `term` taken from the second part. It mostly works with `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package:

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(
    data = xx, 
    cols = everything(), 
    names_sep = '\\.', 
    names_to = c('term_type', 'term'), 
    values_to = 'term_val'
)
```

The result looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  term_type term      term_val
  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>
1 Estimate  Intercept   -0.140
2 Est       Error        0.775
3 Q5        Intercept   -1.57 
4 Q95       Intercept    0.773
5 Estimate  Intercept   -0.140
6 Est       Error        0.777
7 Q5        Intercept   -1.55 
8 Q95       Intercept    0.792
```

But it throws this warning:

```
Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows [2].
```

**Can I use the `names_sep` term to specify that I want the second index of the split string, but only for the second column?** *i.e.* I want `Error` instead of `Est`. I've fixed it for now using an `ifelse`, but I'm wondering if it can be done within the call itself. Myy instinct is there's some clever regex, or perhaps something using `stringr`, but I'm stumped for now...

Comment: The `term_val` values in your resulting tibble don't match any of the values in the dummy data.

Comment: I edited the question to fix this, but some clueless editor rejected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple `.` in some of the column names (`Est.Error.Intercept`).  It may be better to use `names_pattern` to capture groups (`(...)`) that doesn't include any `.` as characters (`[^.]+`).  In addition, specify the end of string with `$`

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(
    data = xx, 
    cols = everything(), 
     names_pattern = "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)$", 
    names_to = c('term_type', 'term'), 
    values_to = 'term_val'
)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  term_type term      term_val
  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>
1 Estimate  Intercept     -0.1
2 Error     Intercept      0.7
3 Q5        Intercept     -1.5
4 Q95       Intercept      0.7
5 Estimate  Intercept     -0.2
6 Error     Intercept      0.8
7 Q5        Intercept     -1.4
8 Q95       Intercept      0.8
```

`"([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)$"` - captures as two groups 1) `([^.]+)` - one or more characters that are not a `.`, followed by a `.` (`\\.`) and 2) the second set of characters that are not a `.` till the end (`$`) of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You may keep `names_sep` using `rename_with` first:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

xx %>% 
  rename_with(~str_replace(., '.Intercept', '_Intercept')) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
  cols = everything(), 
  names_sep = '\\_', 
  names_to = c('term_type', 'term'), 
  values_to = 'term_val'
)
```

```
term_type term      term_val
  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>
1 Estimate  Intercept     -0.1
2 Est.Error Intercept      0.7
3 Q5        Intercept     -1.5
4 Q95       Intercept      0.7
5 Estimate  Intercept     -0.2
6 Est.Error Intercept      0.8
7 Q5        Intercept     -1.4
8 Q95       Intercept      0.8
```

Comment: This is a great solution! However, in my case renaming the intercept only works on the intercept-only models. Models with random slopes return the name of the variable in the column names, of which there are many...